# How do I make sure my Azure Devops Pipeline YAML is in sync to changes I make through the Pipeline UI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have my `azure-pipelines.yml` committed into my Github repo.

I made a few changes to the pipeline via the Azure Devops Pipeline UI by clicking on **Edit**. But my `azure-pipelines.yml` that is committed was not aware of the changes. How do I ensure my committed YAML and Pipeline are in sync?

This is what I did:

- In Azure Devops Pipeline, I accessed my Pipeline
- Clicked on **Edit**
- Clicked on 3 dots -> **Triggers**
- Under **Continuous Integration**
- Added a new branch filter
- Clicked on **Save**

Further adding to this, seems like I am only prompted to create a new PR/Branch in Azure Devops Pipeline if I edit the YAML directly.

Comment: We need some more information here. For one: what are you doing in the 'Azure Devops Pipeline UI'? Are you editing the yaml file, editing the yaml file using [Task assistant for editing YAML files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-150-update#task-assistant-for-editing-yaml-files) or are you using the classic editor? And when you're done, are you talking about Github vs Azure DevOps where files are out of sync? Are you working on the same repo and/or branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaml triggers and UI triggers they are separate trigger controls. They will not synchronize as @Anthony pointed out.

UI triggers will **override the YAML CI trigger**, if you define your pipeline triggers from UI, as below screen showing.

[image]

If you want to add a new branch filter to your pipeline trigger. You can directly edit your azure-pipelines.yml and add the branch to the trigger. Please check [CI triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for informations.

```
trigger:
- master
- releases
```

Answer (score 0):

The two do not synchronize. They are separate functionality. Updating the build tasks in the UI does not modify the azure-pipelines.yml.